# AWS CDK: Sharing a Lambda Function between Stacks Doesn't Work

Tags: aws-cdk

Importing a lambda function from another stack doesn't work when trying to integrate it with a HttpLambdaIntegration. Defining the lambda function and HttpLambdaIntegration in the same stack does work. Why?

I have two stacks: stateful and stateless.  The stateful stack contains resources like the S3 bucket, Api Gateway, and HttpLambdaIntegration. The stateless stack contains the lambda function.

The `HttpLambdaIntegration` uses the lambda function from the stateless stack. I import the lambda function by function ARN (i.e. `lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this, 'function', functionArn)`). However, that doesn't work.

This does work:

```js
const lambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'remixLambda', {entry: <my_path>});
const lambdaIntegration = new HttpLambdaIntegration('lambdaProxy', lambda);
```

If I go to the AWS console, I can see the lambda integration in the API Gateway. If I go to the lambda function, I can't see the integration to API Gateway.  When I try to ping the route, I get an "internal server error". The lambda isn't being invoked so I can't debug logs.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the two stacks in the same app?

Comment: yes, that's not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `fromFunctionArn` here. Instead, follow CDK [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names) and pass construct references via props:

> If the two stacks are in the same AWS CDK app, pass a reference between the two stacks. For example, save a reference to the resource's construct as an attribute of the defining stack (`this.stack.uploadBucket = myBucket`). Then, pass that attribute to the constructor of the stack that needs the resource.

The CDK docs have an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#accessing-resources-in-a-different-stack).  In your case, consider exposing your stateful resources to StatelessStack, rather than the other way around.<sup>1</sup>

Why doesn't `fromFunctionArn` work?  Because the Lambda's resource policy needs to be modified to give the HTTP API permissions, but the construct returned from the `fromFunctionArn` method is a [read-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external) "proxy" object doesn't permit updates to the resource policy.  Unfortunately, this currently fails silently.<sup>2</sup>

---

[1] Using the props approach creates a cross-stack [dependency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#removing-automatic-cross-stack-references).  The direction of the dependency matters.  Having StatelessStack depend on StatefulStack makes it easier to keep StatefulStack while destroying StatelessStack, which is probably what you want.

[2] This is a known issue. The CDK [source implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/55906bbffc01780f380e61f470c091abee4d6835/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/function-base.ts#L340) for `addPermission`, which your code calls indirectly, includes the comment: `// FIXME: @deprecated(v2) - throw an error if calling addPermission on a resource that doesn't support it.`

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.  This solves the issue at hand.  

I think it raises some other issues though. For example, after I create the HttpLambdaIntegration, the lambda integration is set as the default integration for API Gateway.

`    const remixHttpApi = new apigatewayv2.HttpApi(this, `httpApi`, {
      defaultIntegration: lambdaIntegration,
      defaultAuthorizer: authorizer
    });
`

Comment: My prior comment was cut short,  but basically I have a stateful stack creating the ApiGateway resource. The stateless stack creates the lambda function and HttpLambdaIntegration, but the stateful stack needs that HttpLambdaIntegration as the defaultIntegration for the HttpApi. 

It seems like separating stateful and stateless resources can't be fully achieved in this case, there'll be some mixing.

Comment: @shredGnar Glad to help.  I'm not sure what the new issue is.  Perhaps you could ask a new question with the expected vs actual result. One quick suggestion: are you sure your API Gateway belongs in the _stateful_ stack?  Seems stateless.  It probably belongs with the Lambda handlers.

Comment: I was too eager to post the earlier comment. After moving API Gateway to the stateless stack the problem naturally worked itself out.  Thanks again.